# How to create a fixture where every team will play once with the other teams in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Input::

```
Team
T1
T2
T3
T4
```

Output::

```
Team  Opponent
T1    T2
T1    T3
T1    T4
T2    T3
T2    T4
T3    T4
```

Please help us providing the Oracle SQL statement without using PL/SQL block.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's self join.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (team) as
  2    (select 'T1' from dual union all
  3     select 'T2' from dual union all
  4     select 'T3' from dual union all
  5     select 'T4' from dual
  6    )
```

Query:

```
  7  select a.team, b.team opponent
  8  from test a join test b on b.team > a.team
  9  order by 1, 2
 10  /

TEAM       OPPONENT
---------- ----------
T1         T2
T1         T3
T1         T4
T2         T3
T2         T4
T3         T4

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hierarchical query (which avoids the need for a self-join):

```sql
SELECT PRIOR team AS team,
       team AS opponent
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
CONNECT BY PRIOR team < team;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (team) AS
SELECT 'T' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;
```

Outputs:

> | TEAM | OPPONENT |
> | --- | --- |
> | T1 | T2 |
> | T1 | T3 |
> | T1 | T4 |
> | T2 | T3 |
> | T2 | T4 |
> | T3 | T4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=acc93ab4fce9801cbe0463e41c595fd2)*